# invalid SSL_version specified at /usr/share/perl5/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 332

Tags: perl, ssl, ubuntu

Since I upgraded my PC from (k)ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 I receive this error message when trying to send an email using `sendemail`.

Installing an older version of IO::Socket::SSL is not an option. I have the impression that all works as it should and the message is just a warning.

How can I get rid of this message?

---

## SSL.pm

I think the below has to do with the problem (/usr/share/perl5/IO/Socket/SSL.pm).

```
34  use constant DEFAULT_VERSION     => 'SSLv23:!SSLv2';
```

...

```
251         my %default_args = (
252                 Proto => 'tcp',
253                 SSL_server => $is_server,
254                 SSL_use_cert => $is_server,
255                 SSL_check_crl => 0,
256                 SSL_version     => DEFAULT_VERSION,
257                 SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE,
258                 SSL_verify_callback => undef,
259                 SSL_verifycn_scheme => undef,  # don't verify cn
260                 SSL_verifycn_name => undef,    # use from PeerAddr/PeerHost
261                 SSL_npn_protocols => undef,    # meaning depends whether on server or client side
262                 SSL_honor_cipher_order => 0,   # client order gets preference
263         );
```

...

```
332         ${*$self}{'_SSL_ctx'} = IO::Socket::SSL::SSL_Context->new($arg_hash) || return;
```

## sendemail

And at sendemail end I think it is about here in the code:

```
1903     ## Start TLS if possible
1904     if ($conf{'tls_server'} == 1 and $conf{'tls_client'} == 1 and $opt{'tls'} =~ /^(yes|auto)$/) {
1905         printmsg("DEBUG => Starting TLS", 2);
1906         if (SMTPchat('STARTTLS')) { quit($conf{'error'}, 1); }
1907         if (! IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL($SERVER, SSL_version => 'SSLv3 TLSv1')) {
1908             quit("ERROR => TLS setup failed: " . IO::Socket::SSL::errstr(), 1);
1909         }
1910         printmsg("DEBUG => TLS: Using cipher: ". $SERVER->get_cipher(), 3);
1911         printmsg("DEBUG => TLS session initialized :)", 1);
1912 
1913         ## Restart our SMTP session
1914         if (SMTPchat('EHLO ' . $opt{'fqdn'})) { quit($conf{'error'}, 1); }
1915     }
1916     elsif ($opt{'tls'} eq 'yes' and $conf{'tls_server'} == 0) {
1917         quit("ERROR => TLS not possible! Remote SMTP server, $conf{'server'},  does not support it.", 1);
1918     }
```

Comment: Solved it for the time being by changing 'SSLv3 TLSv1'in sendemail line 1907 to 'SSLv3', but editing files installed from a package is *bad*.

Comment: In the new debian version i am still having this issue, but i am now unable to find that line..... None of the another solutions is working except ignoring tls. =(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a bug report on Debian's bug tracker website:  http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=679911

It also states a workaround:

specify `-o tls=no` as an option on the command line.

Thanks @Manolo Díaz on debian.org.

Comment: as workaround it is fine, but fix is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, just take the default (remove the second parameter). See https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL (search for SSL_version). The default is SSLv23:!SSLv3:!SSLv2.

I modified line 1906 in v1.56 to read

```
#        if (! IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL($SERVER, SSL_version => 'SSLv3 TLSv1')) {
    if (! IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL($SERVER)) {
```

(just commenting out the original line)

Answer (score 3):

Easier workaround is:

Replace:

```
m{^(!?)(?:(SSL(?:v2|v3|v23|v2/3))|(TLSv1[12]?))$}i
```

With:

```
m{^(!?)(?:(SSL(?:v2|v3|v23|v2/3))|(TLSv1[12]?))}i
```

Comment: My problem is that this fix breaks Net::Twitter

Comment: 1690 line  /usr/share/perl5/IO/Socket/SSL.pm  in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Since some people still consider the workaround in this answer as the fix and complain about the bug in IO::Socket::SSL: **The problem is not in IO::Socket::SSL but is a bug in sendEmail, which is unmaintained since 2009**. In detail: the syntax for SSL_version is wrong and was not even valid at the time code was written, only IO::Socket::SSL did not complain then. The fix is just to remove the setting of SSL_version from sendemail. See also https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=77401.

Answer (score 2):

[Also a workaround](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=679911), do this if it's required to send from `smtp.gmail.com`:

```
/usr/bin/sendemail on line 1907: 'SSLv3 TLSv1' => 'SSLv3'
```

as temporary solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you still get a certificate error after fixing the SSLversion as shown above, you need to disable certificate checking:

```
if (! IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL($SERVER, SSL_version => 'SSLv23:!SSLv2', SSL_verify_mode => 0)) {
```

Comment: Haven't seen the issue myself for ages and the ubuntu package has been fixed in the mean while. First attempt into fixing this issue should be to patch the system / use most current versions of the software. The alternative solution is interesting from an other point of view though, thnx.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (! IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL($SERVER, SSL_version => 'SSLv3')) {<br>
```

works on debian wheezy with sendEmail 1.56-2 and libio-socket-ssl-perl 1.76-2
and

```
if (! IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL($SERVER, SSL_version => 'SSLv23:!SSLv2')) {<br>
```

works with …/IO/Socket/SSL.pm: 1.74 sendEmail: 1.56 in Ubuntu.

This has been a problem in ubuntu and debian repos for over a year.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I edited sendEmail-v1.55 at line 1884 to change 
'SSLv3 TLSv1' to 'SSLv3'.

OSX 10.10.1

Answer (score -1):

worked for me

```
if (! IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL($SERVER, SSL_version => 'SSLv23:!SSLv2')) {
```