# invalid SSL_version specified at /usr/share/perl5/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 368

Tags: linux, email, ssl, smtp, nagios

```
SMTP SEND CRITICAL - invalid SSL_version specified at /usr/share/perl5/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 368
```

I am using a nagios script /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_smtp_send that sends an email using gmail.

WHen I add a diagnostic I get this:

```
SMTP SEND CRITICAL - invalid SSL_version specified(SSLv3 TLSv1) at /usr/share/perl5/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 368
```

Ubuntu 14.04 with standard nagios from the distro.

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The code in check_smtp_send is buggy. It either directly specifies an invalid string for `SSL_version` or uses a module which does so (the very old and unmaintained module `Net::SMTP::TLS` is known for this bug). It might be that it is fixed in newer versions of the code.

But given that I have no idea which OS you are running, which package this code belongs to and if this is a known bug or not I cannot really help instead saying that it is either already fixed and you should upgrade or this needs to be fixed. In the latter case I can help but than I would need to have access to the code in question.

More information about this kind of problem you might find at [invalid SSL_version specified at /usr/share/perl5/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 332](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53065/invalid-ssl-version-specified-at-usr-share-perl5-io-socket-ssl-pm-line-332). There you find the direct cause (bad SSL_version), the indirect cause (stricter checks of SSL_version in newer versions of IO::Socket::SSL) and how to fix it in the code (fix SSL_version in the buggy code, don't work around by changing IO::Socket::SSL).

Based on https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Email-and-Groupware/check_email_delivery/details:
- the package was last updated 2011
- it uses the old `Net::SMTP::TLS` which causes the problem

Workaround is to simply remove the part which sets a wrong SSL_version from Net::SMTP::TLS. This should be line 182, see https://metacpan.org/source/AWESTHOLM/Net-SMTP-TLS-0.12/lib/Net/SMTP/TLS.pm#L182.

Before:

```
    if(not IO::Socket::SSL::socket_to_SSL($me->{sock},
            SSL_version     =>   "SSLv3 TLSv1")){
                    croak "Couldn't start TLS: ".IO::Socket::SSL::errstr."\n";
     }
```

After:

```
    if(not IO::Socket::SSL::socket_to_SSL($me->{sock})){
                    croak "Couldn't start TLS: ".IO::Socket::SSL::errstr."\n";
    }
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 with standard nagios from the distro.

Comment: @k-h:  see edit for workaround.

Comment: Hi @steffen-ullrich,

Net::SMTP::TLS.pm line 182 is part of a larger statement from lines 181-184:

    if(not IO::Socket::SSL::socket_to_SSL($me->{sock},
                    SSL_version     =>   "SSLv3 TLSv1")){
                            croak "Couldn't start TLS:".IO::Socket::SSL::errstr."\n";
            }
I tried removing the SSL_version parameter, I tried setting SSL_version to SSLv3, TLSv12, I tried removing the whole if statement but just got errors.

Comment: @k-h: see edit for how to remove it properly.